# Clustering without labels

Tags: clustering

I want to cluster the data points into 2 clusters. For that, I used a deep neural network but I have no labels to backpropagate. How can I backpropagate? which loss function I can use in this problem

Is there any way to do it without using autoencoders or it is impossible?

Any kind of reference is helpful

Comment: Is it necessary to use a deep neural network only? Can't simpler techniques like k-means or dbscan work?

Comment: My solution is with deep learning

Comment: have you explored self organizing maps?

Comment: You would have to define a loss function which penalizes a bad clustering, whatever that means in your case.